# Converting dif Video to mp4

Tags: 22.04, video, video-conversion

I've been able to recover an old family video from a broken disc. Unfortunately I was only able to recover a **dif** video w/ 1.3gb.
Does anybody know a way of converting this - to me unknown - format to mp4 or something compareable. I have Ubuntu 22.04 and not much knowledge of video/codec stuff. Thanks!

Comment: I think this may be DV-DIF format. See here for conversion options https://www.videoconverterfactory.com/tips/dv-to-mp4.html. I would opt for the VLC method.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Weird enough the file shows a *.dif ending. Although it totally makes sense, I cannot import the file to VLC.

Answer (score 0):

It's also known as DV-DIF format see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DV

You can check online converters like https://cloudconvert.com/dv-to-mp4

Or else can check some video converter softwares like Prism Video Converter https://www.nchsoftware.com/howto/convert/dv_to_mp4_files.html

Also by using VLC Media Player you can convert DIF to MP4 https://www.businessinsider.com/guides/tech/how-to-convert-to-mp4-on-vlc?IR=T

Comment: Thank you for your response. Weird enough the file shows a *.dif ending. Although it totally makes sense, I cannot import the file to VLC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).